# Why use C# rather than Java API of ArcGIS Engine (or vice versa)?

Tags: c#, arcgis-engine, java

I'm going to lead a development of an ArcGIS Engine application and facing the choice mentioned in the title. We have all licenses to develop our application in C#, so Microsoft's licences are out of the equation.

I've heard (from colleagues and from the internet) that for some unknown reasons it's better to use C# instead of Java. Is that true?

The **[ArcGIS Engine website](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/arcgisengine)** says that its API is available in both C# and Java. I know that ArcObjects are written in COM manner in C++, so they still need to be wrapped and it shouldn't matter whether it's in C# or Java. I also am aware of the fact that C# API has been available longer than the Java one, but does it make it more stable or preferable?

We are starting our application from scratch and it doesn't really matter for us whether it'll be written in C# or Java. Are there any reasonable reasons why one should you one or the other?

Comment: Have you considered one of the Runtime SDK's instead of ArcEngine?  ArcEngine is starting to show its age.

Comment: COM is already slow enough, Java is going to make it even slower. So will .NET but not as bad: http://www.pierssen.com/arcgis/upload/misc/python_arcobjects.pdf#page=4

Comment: This might have been improved since that benchmark, however: http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/java_ao_adf/conceptualhelp/engine/index.html#performance

Comment: @KirkKuykendall I was sure that using ArcEngine is the only to buuild standalone applications with ArcGis functions. What's the difference between them?